# Multiple-Inheritence: Something unexpected is happening...?

Tags: python, oop, output, multiple-inheritance

I am teaching myself oops concept in python. I accidently typed `B().__init__()` inside **init** method of child class C. This is the code.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A')

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('B')

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('C')
        B().__init__()

c1 = C()
```

and this is the output

```
C
B
B
```

Why B is being printed 2 times?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why this B is being printed 2 times?

Comment: Use a debugger and set a breakpoint. ;) Seriously, you create a `C` instance (which implies creating `A`, `B`, and finally `C`) and you create another, completely independent `B` instance. That said, take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, you never state what you would have expected instead.

Comment: Because creating an instance of the B class by writing `B()` automatically executes B's `__init__` method. By writing `B().__init__()`, you actually call B's `__init__` two times - one implicit call when creating the instance (`B()`), and one explicit call to `__init__`.

Answer (score 3):

You create an instance of B in the **init**() method of C. Then you call **init**() method of B explicitly. You want to have:

```
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('C')
        super().__init__(self)
```

Comment: This is not quite complete. Both `A.__init__` and `B.__init__` should be calling `super().__init__` as well, if the intention is to use `super` correctly.

Comment: A and B inherit from object only and object.__init__() does nothing. Moreover for some scenarios it's actually desirable to override __init__() completely so A and B implementation are free to initialize their instances in a different way if the developer knows what he/she is doing.

Comment: That's not how `super` works. It does not invoke `__init__` for any particular *static* base class, but for the next class in the MRO for the `type(self)`.

Comment: Where did I say that it calls __init__() for particular static base class??? Of course it's going to follow MRO and will invoke A.__init__() in this case because C inherits from A and B and A has __init__() defined.

Comment: And what if `A` inherited from something *other* than `object`? What if `C.__init__` is being called from an instance of a *subclass* of `C`? If you are going to use `super`, you need to use it consistently across the *entire* hierarchy.

Comment: "And what if A inherited from something other than object?" But it doesn't. And that is exactly my point. Please prove usefulness of "super().__init__()" in a class which inherits from object only. Live long and prosper.

Answer (score 1):

according to python documentation it says that
**_init__** is a special Python method that is automatically called when memory is
allocated for a new object.
we can also call **__init__** method explictly and that is what you have done in above code .
 **B()** is constructor invocation and first **__init__** has been called.
and after **__init__()** has been called by you explictly.  so 2 times
call has been made.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to make sure that parent base classes get initialized is as follows (you did not specify whether your Python is Python 2 or Python 3, so I am ensuring that your classes inherit from class `object`):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('A')
        super(A, self).__init__()
        #super().__init__() # alternate call if Python 3

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('B')
        super(B, self).__init__()
        #super().__init__() # alternate call  if Python 3

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('C')
        super(C, self).__init__()
        #super().__init__() # alternate call if Python 3

c1 = C()
```

Or you can simply do the following:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('A')

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print('B')

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('C')
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)

c1 = C()
```

Comment: Let's assume the OP is using Python 3; otherwise, he is defining old-style classes, which is just all *sorts* of wrong.

Comment: @chepner yes i am using python3. what new style classes should i use here?

Comment: The new-style/old-style distinction was only relevant in Python 2. All classes in Python 3 are "new-style" classes; there is no other option.

Comment: @MayankPant If you are using Python3, then all classes ultimately derive from object and are thus always 'new style' classes.